# In React native IAP not able to Consume the products in Android

Tags: android, react-native

In react native iap new version 12.8.2 Im not able to consume the products in android ..In previous version of rniap we can consume the products with ConsumePurchase method but now I can not find any method to make my products consumable. When I bought one plan and use all the questions then Im not able to buy that plan again .So I want to make it consumable and want to buy that plan again
Can Anyone Please help!!!!!

RNIAP.finishTransaction(),getAvailablePurchases(),RNIap.finishTransaction({
purchase:
Platform.OS == 'ios'
? res.transactionId
: res.purchaseToken,
isConsumable: true,
developerPayloadAndroid: '',})

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the whole **res** object to purchase property.

Like this: `finishTransaction({purchase: res, isConsumable: true})`

Comment: Yes ,I tried this but still my response goes in error and this thing not helped me.If you have any other suggestion please help!!!

Comment: How are you retrieving the "res" object?